# Как убрать разделяющие линии между элементами списка

Tags: java, android, adapter, списки

в android api есть готовые адаптеры. Мне требуется разместить список рекордов используя собственный фон и без разделяющий линий между элементами списка. Какой готовый адаптер позволяет это сделать?  Во всех примерах что нагуглил вижу разделяющую черту между элементами списка.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html   подойдет

Comment: подойдет любой адаптер, который принимает данные вашего типа, дивидеры вообще не зависят от адаптера. Наличие и вид, либо отсутствие дивидеров в списке указывается через атрибут самого списка `android:dividers`, если речь идет о `ListView`, либо `RecyclerView`, который не добавляет дивидеров вовсе

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте просто для ListView проставить отсутствие  разделителей в разметке:

```
<ListView
  android:divider="@null"
  android:background="#00FF00"/>
```

Comment: Работает. Исправил в ответе Вашу опечатку. Ну и так же , если мне нужен фон, не к каждому элементу, а общий под всем списком , то просто ,например, в Linearloyaut добавляю атрибут с фоном.